# Python - Waiting for input from lots of sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on a simple experiment in Python.  I have a "master" process, in charge of all the others, and every single process has a connection via unix socket to the master process.  I would like to be able for the master process to be able to monitor all of the sockets for a response - but there could theoretically be almost a hundred of them.  How would threads impact the memory and performance of the application?  What would be the best solution?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One hundred simultaneous threads might be pushing the reasonable limits of threading. If you find this is the cleanest way to organize your code, I'd say give it a try, but threading really doesn't scale very far.

What works better is to use a technique like [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) to wait for one of the sockets to be readable / writable / or has an error to report. This mechanism lets you go to sleep until something interesting happens, handle as many sockets have content to handle, and then go back to sleep again, all in a single thread of execution. Removing the multi-threading can often reduce chances for errors, and this style of programming should get you into the hundreds of connections no trouble. (If you want to go beyond about 100, I'd use the `poll` functionality instead of `select` -- constantly rebuilding the list of interesting file descriptors takes time that `poll` does not require.)

Something to consider is the [Python Twisted Framework](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). They've gone to some length to provide a consistent way to hook callbacks onto events for this exact sort of programming. (If you're familiar with `node.js`, it's a bit like that, but Python.) I must admit a slight aversion to Twisted -- I never got very far in their documentation without being utterly baffled -- but [a lot of people made it further in the docs than I did](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/SuccessStories). You might find it a better fit than I have.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.  But is there any reason I might not want to use poll on a smaller number of sockets?

Comment: No, `poll` would work well for smaller numbers of sockets too. I think the `select` interface is that little bit easier than the `poll` interface, but they're close enough.

Comment: `epoll` definitely makes it easier to use _partial reads_ on sockets in any given iteration of the event handling loop. (`select` and `poll` would require you to _remember_ that you've done partial reads -- or never perform partial reads.)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to conduct comparative tests of threads versus processes for socket handling is to use the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#module-SocketServer) in Python's standard library.  You can easily switch approaches (while keeping everything else the same) by inheriting from either *ThreadingMixIn* or *ForkingMixIn*.  Here is a [simple example](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins) to get you started.

Another alternative is a [select/poll approach](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select) using non-blocking sockets in a single process and a single thread.

If you're interested in software that is already fully developed and highly evolved, consider these high-performance Python based server packages:

- The [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework uses the async single process, single thread style.
- The [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) framework is similar (less evolved, less full featured, but easier to understand)
- And [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) which is a high-performance forking server.